# How to change value in a case statement but keep the over all count

Tags: sql

I want to be able to create a SQL query where I can grab the average duration of all users in a site and change any use that exceeds the limit to the cap, instead of using a where the function to drop them all.

Current query

```
select 
date,
clientID,
count(*) as total users,
(sum(duration)/count(*)) as avgdur
Where 
--this is in seconds
Duration < 3600
```

This is currently resulting in a smaller user count, but I want to keep all the users and change any duration of a user that exceeds the limit to match the limit.

| Date | ClientID | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-10-2022 | 101 | 5000 |
| 01-10-2022 | 102 | 200 |
| 01-10-2022 | 103 | 600 |
| 01-10-2022 | 104 | 1000 |
| 01-10-2022 | 105 | 7000 |
| 01-10-2022 | 107 | 200 |

The results would only get an average duration of 500 because it is excluding 2 users.
I want to keep the number of users the same and change the duration of the users who are exceeding the limit of 3600 to be set to the average or the limit whish is 36000.
IE> instead of the client having a duration of 5000 to be set to the average or 3600.

avgdur query results = 500
avgdur expected Results = 1533

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example (that is, with tables) of what you are trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Please provide both sample input and expected result as tables in your question. Calculating an average instead of using AVG is mostly a bad idea.

Comment: added the table for clarity

Comment: What should your *result table* be for your example?

Comment: Please tag your DBMS

Comment: Please don't describe the expected result in words only, but add it as second table to your question. I don't understand where the number 1533 comes from. Should the duration be 3600 or 1533? It seems you can't decide what you want? ;)

Comment: I thought it was clear i added expected and actual results. 1533 is the expected results and 500 is the actual rresults

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: What dbms are you using? Most dialects now support LEAST(value, cap).

Answer (score 0):

Your question will be much clearer and better to understand if you add the expected result as table.
As I understand your question, the desired outcome should be this:

| Startdate | ClientID | total_users | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-10-2022 | 101 | 6 | 1533 |
| 01-10-2022 | 102 | 6 | 1533 |
| 01-10-2022 | 103 | 6 | 1533 |
| 01-10-2022 | 104 | 6 | 1533 |
| 01-10-2022 | 105 | 6 | 1533 |
| 01-10-2022 | 107 | 6 | 1533 |

This can be done using `COUNT`, `AVG` and `LEAST`:

```
SELECT
startdate, clientid, 
COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_users,
AVG(LEAST(duration,3600)) OVER() AS duration
FROM yourtable;
```

Try out here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9ZNDtTG2)

If this isn't what you wanted to do, please edit your question and add the expected result as table.

The query shown here will work on most DBMS, but not on all. So if you encounter errors when executing it, tag your DBMS and replace the parts of the query with the corresponding functions of your DBMS.